# Vue multiple aplication instance does not render data

Tags: vuejs3

I have 2 vue3 instance in my application and it is early app. When i try to render data from those 2 instance it give the result `[Vue warn]: Property "message" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance` from one of my instance.

How i can render data from those instances?

`first instance`

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const app = createApp({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
    data () {
        return {
          message_base: "Halo!",
        }
    },
})

app.mount('#app')
```

`another instance` that give the error result

```js
const navbarapp = createApp({
  el: '#navbarapp',
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  data () {
    return {
      message: "Halo, another instance!",
    }
  },
})

navbarapp.mount('#navbarapp')
```

`simple.html`

```html
<html>
...

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <p>[[ message_base ]]</p>

    <div id="navbarapp">
      <p> [[ message ]] </p>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't have anymore code? No template here? The error is quite self-explanatory: you probably have mixed some things or forgot to have the state defined in the same scope as your app.

Comment: Try `{{ message_base }}` rather. Wait, why are you changing the delimiters?

Comment: Also, your `navbarapp` SPA is nested inside of `app`, not sure that nesting 2 SPA is the way to go. You should probably try to avoid that kind of setup.

Comment: The delimiters probably need to be nested somewhere else rather: https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-compileroptions Not sure that it's availanle from the top level of the `createApp`.

Comment: i change delimiter because of using django as a backend, and use vue inline template there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are nesting `navbarapp` inside `app`

change this:

```
<div id="app">
  <p>[[ message_base ]]</p>

    <div id="navbarapp">
     <p> [[ message ]] </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="app">
  <p>[[ message_base ]]</p>
</div>

<div id="navbarapp">
  <p> [[ message ]] </p>
</div>
```

here's the DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/duddee/Lu1a8tsd/1/